# Determining whether 2 logical statements are equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I recently encountered a problem which is to determine whether the following statements are logically equivalent to each other. The statements are:

$$\text{$(\exists x\in U)[P(x)\land Q(x)]$ and $[(\exists x\in U)P(x)]\land[(\exists x\in U)Q(x)]$}$$

Suppose $(\exists x\in U)[P(x)\land Q(x)]$ is true. Let $x = a \in U$ s.t. $P(a)$ and $Q(a)$ is true. So both $P(a)$ and $Q(a)$ are true.

Suppose $(\exists x\in U)[P(x)\land Q(x)]$ is false. Then its negation: $(\forall x \in U)[\neg P(x) \lor\neg Q(x)]$ is true. The negation holds true whenever $P(x)$ is false or $Q(x)$ is false for any $x \in U$.

Let $x \in U$ s.t. $\neg P(x) \lor\neg Q(x)$ is true, hence, we consider 2 cases:

Case 1: $P(x)$ is false

Since $P(x)$ is false for any $x\in U$, $(\exists x\in U)P(x)$ is false, hence $[(\exists x\in U)P(x)]\land[(\exists x\in U)Q(x)]$ must be false.

Case 2: $Q(x)$ is false

Since $Q(x)$ is false for any $x\in U$, $(\exists x\in U)Q(x)$ is false, hence, $[(\exists x\in U)P(x)]\land[(\exists x\in U)Q(x)]$ must be false.

Since when $(\exists x\in U)[P(x)\land Q(x)]$ is true, $[(\exists x\in U)P(x)]\land[(\exists x\in U)Q(x)]$ is also true. And when $(\exists x\in U)[P(x)\land Q(x)]$ is false, $[(\exists x\in U)P(x)]\land[(\exists x\in U)Q(x)]$ is also false.

Therefore we can conclude that they are logically equivalent.

I would like to know whether my answer is valid and whether there is bug in my answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Without attacking your analysis, the two statements **can't** be equivalent.  The LHS statement is asserting that there is a single value $x$ that simultaneously makes the statements $P,Q$ both true.  The RHS statement is asserting that there are two (**possibly distinct**) values $x_1, x_2$ such that $x_1$ makes the statement $P$ true, and $x_2$ makes the statement $Q$ true.  Therefore, the RHS statement, which is a **weaker** assertion than the LHS statement, makes no guarantee that there exists a single value $x$ that **simultaneously** makes both statements $P$ and $Q$ true.

Answer (score 1):

The two statements are not equivalent, since if

- $Px:=x$ is even
- $Qx:=x$ is odd
- $U:=$ the set of positive integers

then the left statement is false but the right statement true.

---

I would present your argument more readabily by rewriting many of the symbols (for example, the quantifiers) as words, and perhaps using fewer parentheses (illustrated below). The human (as opposed to machine) reader will appreciate this.

Anyway, the first part of your proof is correct, but in the second part you have actually— sort of —proven $$∀x{\in}U\;\Big((¬Px ∨ ¬Qx)   →       ¬(Px  ∧  Qx)     \Big) \tag1 $$ instead of the (false) statement $$∀x{\in}U\;(¬Px ∨ ¬Qx)   →       ¬\Big((   ∃x{\in}U\;Px)  ∧    (∃x{\in}U\;Qx)     \Big)  .$$

> Let $x \in U$ s.t. $\neg P(x) \lor\neg Q(x)$ is true

Here, you are considering one arbitrary element of $U;$ let's call it $a.$

> , hence, we
> consider 2 cases:
>
> Case 1: $P(x)$ is false
>
> Since $P(x)$ is false for any $x\in U$,

Here, you should still be referring to the specific element $a.$

> $(\exists x\in U)P(x)$ is
> false, hence $[(\exists x\in U)P(x)]\land[(\exists x\in U)Q(x)]$ must
> be false.

Logically, the part before "hence" is just `P(a) is false`, while the part after "hence" is just `P(a)∧ Q(a) is false`.

Case 2 contains the same error.

Then, at the end, since $a$ is an *arbitrary* element of $U,$ we can correctly conclude that $(1)$ is true. This entire proof is irrelevant to disproving the given statement, but I'm critiquing it to reveal the "bug" (heheh) that you are asking about.

> The negation holds true whenever $P(x)$ is false or $Q(x)$ is false for any $x \in U$.

I had to read this twice because it is written like it could mean either of these:
$$(\forall x\;Sx)\implies T\\
\forall x\;(Sx\implies T)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the set $\{x|P(x)\}$ and $B$ be the set $\{x|Q(x)\}$

The first premise is therefore $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$ and the second $A\ne\emptyset\land B\ne\emptyset$.

The second premise doesn't enforce the first (if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$ is indeterminate).

For example $A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}$.